# SharePoint PNP/JS Azure Function cant get list items

Tags: sharepoint, azure-functions, sharepoint-online

In have created an Azure function in Visual Code following this example(https://simonagren.github.io/azurefunction-v2-pnpjs/). But the code below returns an empty array. I'm using pnp/sp and pnp/nodejs

```
sp.setup({
    sp: {
        fetchClientFactory: () => {
            return new SPFetchClient(
              `https://[mydomain].sharepoint.com/sites/[mysite name]/`, 
              process.env.spId, 
              process.env.spSecret);
        },
    },
});

const leaders = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("LeaderGroup").items.get();
context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
    body: "Result: " + leaders.map( l=>l.Leader).join(',')
};
```

If a use another pnp endpoint const web = await sp.web.select("Title").expand('Lists').get(); 
I get all the lists form the web as expected. What am I doing wrong? I've used this method before in spfx/react webparts without any problems.

Comment: According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint#create-update-and-delete-lists , they have used just `sp.web.lists.getByTitle("LeaderGroup")` can you try by removing .items.get() am not sure though

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The documentation you are refering to is using CSOM. I use pnp/sp.

Comment: How are you authenticating your call to SharePoint?